# Compiling C++ file with linked header file in VSC IDE

Tags: c++, header-files

I would like to compile my main.cpp file within VSC (using mac if relevant), which includes a linked header file "library.h" and the corresponding "library.cpp" file (see below, all in the same folder).

When using another IDE, i.e. CLion, I can create a CMakeLists.txt file that includes the corresponding header files as executable (with adding "add_executable(complex main.cpp Complex.cpp Complex.h)" into the .txt). There, I have no trouble running main.cpp, but in VSC the usual compiling of the main.cpp file gives the error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "function(int)",
> referenced from:
> _main in main-de82ff.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
> see invocation)

Unfortunately I couldn't find a quick fix on how to compile all files together in a comfortable way. What do I have to change in order for it to work in VSC?

Thank you in advance!!

The code:

1. main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "library.h"

int main(){
    function(1);
    return 0;
}
```

2. library.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "library.h"

void function(int x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

3. library.h

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_COMPLEX_H

void function(int x);

#endif
```

Comment: Btw you don't need to put headers in `add_executable`, only source files `.cpp`

Comment: How does `CMakeLists.txt` look like? Do you use `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: So how do you expect it to find code from `library.cpp`, if you never compile it? Or you meant that `library.cpp == Complex.cpp`?

Comment: *Btw you don't need to put headers in add_executable, only source files .cpp* You should put headers if you want the generated make our project file to watch if headers are updated and compile dependent source files

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov sorry you are right, I copy pasted it wrong. the CMakeLists file generated by CLion looks like this: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp library.h library.cpp)
`